# c++ tron Player lightcycle move in one direction

Tags: c++, input, getch, kbhit

I am trying to have the player lightcycle keep moving in one direction without stopping until the player pushes a button to move it in another direction. I am not sure how I could do this with kbhit so please give me some advice! thanks.

```
void Lightcycle(){
    if (kbhit()) {// get user key input
    char GetCh = getch(); // GetCh equal to the button the user presses
    if (GetCh == 'w'){PlayerX = PlayerX - 1;}
    else if (GetCh == 's'){PlayerX = PlayerX +1;}
    else if (GetCh == 'd'){PlayerY = PlayerY +1;}
    else if (GetCh == 'a'){PlayerY = PlayerY - 1;}
}// end kbhit
}// end function
```

Comment: Rather than having input move the player directly, give the player a direction and have input modify that, then just move the player in the direction they are pointed.

Comment: can you show an example in code please? i have no idea how I would apply that in actual code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you'll need a global variable called `direction` and change that, like:

```
if (GetCh == 'w'){direction=1;}
else if (GetCh == 's'){direction=2;}
else if (GetCh == 'd'){direction=3;}
else if (GetCh == 'a'){direction=4;}
```

Then you'll need, somewhere in your game loop, to handle the player movement constatly, like:

```
while(gameRunning){
    // Random code handling game goes here
    ...
    if (direction== 1){PlayerX = PlayerX - 1;}
    else if (direction== 2){PlayerX = PlayerX +1;}
    else if (direction== 3){PlayerY = PlayerY +1;}
    else if (direction== 3){PlayerY = PlayerY - 1;}
    ...
    // Other code handling game goes here
}
```